# Frequency Space Bounds for Fourier Transformed Function Variables

Tags: fourier-transform, computational-mathematics

Lets say we have an arbitrary periodic function $u(x, y, z)$ where $x, y, z \in [0, 2 \pi]$ and represented on a computational mesh $\text{Ni} \times \text{Nj} \times \text{Nk}$. If we take the Discrete 3D-Fourier Transform on $u$ to obtain $\hat{u}(\hat{x}, \hat{y}, \hat{z})$, how would we find what the domains for $\hat{x}, \hat{y}, \hat{z}$ would be?

Conceptually, it seems that the "longest" wave that could fit within this mesh would be the length of the domain, and the "shortest" wave that could fit within this mesh would be twice the interval between grid points. Wouldn't that mean that the domain would be:
$$\hat{x} \in \left[\frac{2 \pi}{2 \pi}, \frac{2 \pi}{2 \pi /\text{Ni}} \right] = [1, \text{Ni}]$$

How would that work with the fact that the Fourier Transform would also output both pairs of the complex conjugate?

Note: I originally posted this on the Computational Physics SE, but deleted it as I felt it would be more relevant here.

@HyeongmukLIM, let's say I have a function $y(x) = \sin(x)$. I can compute this discretely over [-π, π] and Ni = 10. Y(ξ) will now be:

```
[-1.2246468e-16+0.00000000e+00j -1.2246468e-16+5.00000000e+00j
 -1.2246468e-16+3.41691513e-16j -1.2246468e-16+0.00000000e+00j
 -1.2246468e-16-8.06624243e-17j -1.2246468e-16-2.22044605e-16j
 -1.2246468e-16+8.06624243e-17j -1.2246468e-16+2.22044605e-16j
 -1.2246468e-16-3.41691513e-16j -1.2246468e-16-5.00000000e+00j]
```

Discounting random floating point errors, you can quickly see that there are:

```
-1.2246468e-16+5.00000000e+00j
-1.2246468e-16-5.00000000e+00j
```

Comment: Your guess seems correct. A simple way to find the values for $\hat{x}=k$ is to notice that $f_{k}(x)=\exp ikx$ serves as basis vectors of the functions on the $x$-space. The interval between different $x$'s and that of $k$'s should multiply to $2\pi$.

Comment: Aside, could you elaborate on what you mean by "How would that work with the fact that the Fourier Transform would also output both pairs of the complex conjugate?"

Comment: @HyeongmukLIM, see the edit to my post.

Comment: Your code correctly outputs ten numbers, one for each value of $\hat{x}$. They must be five pairs of complex conjugates since the original function $f(x)=\sin x$ is real. In fact, they are exactly $\pm 5.0j$ and 8 copies of zero, as you can see here: https://www.statlect.com/matrix-algebra/discrete-Fourier-transform-of-cosine-and-sine